# Access Android Emails through Content Provider

Tags: android, email

I have four questions regarding Android default email program.  Please help me to answer the questions respectively.
Thanks in Advance

1) How can we access the Device Database?

2) How can we setup email on Emulator?

3) Can we read Email Content Through Email Content Provider like (AttachementProvider.java) 
I have found in Git

4) Can anyone tell me the correct Email URI
I have found the URI that is not working
"content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider"

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How can we access the Device Database ?

You can't.

> 2) How can we setup email on Emulator ?

I would assume that you tap on the icon in the launcher and follow the prompts, the way you would set it up on a regular phone. Bear in mind that this application may not exist on all phones.

> 3) Can we read Email Content Through Email Content Provider like ( AttachementProvider.java) i have found in Git

There is no documented and supported API for any email client in the Android SDK.

> 4) can any one tell me the corret Email URI i have found the URI that is not working "content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider"

I repeat, there is no documented and supported API for any email client in the Android SDK. [You have been specifically told not to use undocumented content providers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html), since they will be changed without warning and, again, may not exist on all devices.