# Android, reading emails from SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I would like to write an application which first detects the email accounts configured and then scans the contents of each email account inbox. The purpose is to check for a specific email. The precise details are not important.

Does anyone have any ideas how to detect configured email accounts and then read the contents of the inbox for each account?

Sorry if this is a dumb question it is my first android app.

Many Thanks
Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

While you make be able to use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to get a list of email accounts, I don't think you can [access the email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811608/access-android-emails-through-content-provider/3812027#3812027) by any currently supported method. Sorry.